# How to filter request based on domain in spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have one war file for my application and I will be using 2 domains to access it. For example I want to access admin.jsp using admin.mydomain.com/adminpage and other jsp pages I want to access with local.mydomain.com.

Also, admin.jsp should be only accessible via admin.mydomain.com and not via local.mydomain.com. How to do this in spring-security / spring-mvc? Is there a support in spring framework for this?

Any help on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [`RequestMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/util/matcher/RequestMatcher.html), and maybe like

```
HostOnlyRequestMatch(String relativePath, String hostname)
```

and then override the `boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request)` method, and if the `relativePath` and `hostname` are same with request, return `true`.

Add the `requestMatcher` to `http` like this:

```
 http
     .authorizeRequests()
         .requestMatcher(new HostOnlyRequestMatch("/admin", "admin.mydomain.com")).permitAll()
         .antMatchers("/admin").denyAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to configure proxy (e.g. Nginx) to route your requests to your application server (e.g Tomcat) properly. Read here for more details https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score -1):

You can get the requested url from request object in you mvc controller and if it is not form correct domain then you can throw or show proper error based on your project. Following is the code snippet

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/adminpage")
public class AdminPageController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getAdminPage(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
      if(!url.contains("admin.mydomain.com")) {
          throw RuntimeException("Not accessible through this domain.");
          // You can implement your own logic of showing error here
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Security is a cross-cutting concern and shouldn't be implemented in a controller! Spring Security, a HandlerInterceptor, or a @ControllerAdvice would all be better mechanisms for this.