# Restrict API access by domain name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to secure my Spring Boot API by limiting allowed requests to a certain domain name, but I found only restriction by IP addresses.
The allowed domaine name is where my second app running into.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/web-api/**").hasIpAddress("test.domain.ma");
```

Is there a way to set up domain name filtering?

I'm using SpringBoot 2.2.7

Comment: Isn't CORS what you are looking for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter request based on domain in spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252884/how-to-filter-request-based-on-domain-in-spring-mvc)